# Was coerced into setting up 2 Google Phone Accounts and don't know how to delete them

Tags: google, scam

I received a text after posting on Craigslist and putting in my iphone number for texting.  The text said "Hi i am Jacqueline..wanna buy your Wooden Organizer - $40.  Urgently.  Can I call you now?"  I said yes.  They said they only had a Google phone so can they call me now.  I said yes.  The next text said to please press [2 digit number they gave me] when receiving my call to connect with me.  I did so and the recording said "Thank you for setting up a Google Account."  I hung up and received another text saying the person made a mistake and was sorry and to please press [a different 2 digit number] when he/she called again and there would not be a problem.  I did so and received the same outgoing message.  Shocked, I hung up and realized I'd been scammed.

I blocked the number from my iphone and deleted the message text after taking a photo of it.  I'm afraid someone is going to make extraordinary expensive phone calls all over the world with these new Google Accounts I've set up.  I don't know what to do or how to delete these phone accounts and I can't seem to find out how.  Every time i try to google "How do I delete only a "google phone account" [not a google account] they only tell me how to delete my gmail accounts.  Help!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a google support question than a security question

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so firstly we need to understand, what they are after is your number so they can use it for google voice calls and mail most likely. You did not create two voice accounts, what you did was ***attempt*** to link your phone number to someone else's voice account **twice**. What i think happened here is that the first time they messed something up or google got in their way, so they opted to try a second time. They may or may not have gotten it the second time we are not sure.

This scam will almost always appear in the form:

- I want to buy your item from [marketplace]
- I cant wait and must call you now
- I need you to input 2 digits because im using X

X being conference calling, google voice, or any other reason to input a code to connect to somone. If you input the code you linked your phone to their google voice account and they can do things on your behalf.

The solution here is to create your own google voice account and link your number to that account to stop them from being able to use it any further, since you control the phone you are the only one with the ability to do this. i.e. they cannot get it back without getting you to re-link to their account.

First go to [Google Voice](https://voice.google.com/u/0/about) and start the process. Select your device:
[image]

Then you will be brought to a page with further instructions. Follow them. Eventually you will be asked perhaps to login to an existing google account, do so, or create one if you don't have one.

Once you are ready to link your number you should be able to go to your google account, get into your voice account and select the following:

[image]

At this point it will ask you to which number you wish the account to be linked. Type in your scammed number. You will get a call from the exact same number (which is, 202-455-8888, I believe) you got before asking for the exact same kind of 2 digit code, which i assume will be sent to your email or via text, or they'll give it to you over the phone and you'll input it on the site. Do that.

You may also be able to see here if you were too late in avoiding their use, but im not sure, as i don't know if account transfers preserve history.

However, any previous links to your number at this point should be unauthorized for use.

At this point it may ask you to port your number, **do not do so**. Porting will issue a stop on your current phone contract, not something you may want, you will create a new phone number to use with google voice.

Use the google voice number for online selling in the future (might as well), this has the benefit of not giving away your real number to anyone while selling things.